# Change Fontawesome icon color

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am trying to create a shape like this via CSS :

[image]

I currently managed to create this.

```css
i.fa {
  border-radius: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #888;
  padding: 0.7em 0.7em;
  background-color : #06283d
}
```

```html
<body>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <i class="fa fa-regular fa-spinner fa-5x"></i>
</body>
```

Is there a way to change the loading icon to white instead of black?

Comment: Add `color: white;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean add `color:white`?

```css
i.fa {
  border-radius: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #888;
  padding: 0.7em 0.7em;
  background-color: #06283d;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <i class="fa fa-regular fa-spinner fa-spin fa-5x"></i>

</body>
```

Comment: this is one of the most asked question of stackoverfow, vote to close instead of answering

Answer (score 0):

```css
i{font-size: 50px;color: #ff0;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
</head>
<body>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-camera-retro"></i>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add an explanation. Also it is preferred if you use OP's code instead of using completely different library and icons